# Import IISLog Data Into table Sqlserver

Tags: database, logging, proc

**Hi all friends have a double question
First, how to write a procedure that can store an IIslog in a table in the database
Second, how do we define the procedure as a job that can be set at intervals?
Thanks so much for your guidance**

Comment: How about starting from here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I did it myself:
CREATE PROC SP_IISLog
( 
@TABLENAME VARCHAR(50), 
@PATHNAME VARCHAR(50) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @SSQL NVARCHAR(50); 
SET @SSQL= ' BULK INSERT ' + @TABLENAME + ' FROM ''' + @PATHNAME + ''' WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
) GO'
exec sp_ExeCuteSQL @SSQL 
END